# Browser redirects to https

Tags: ssl, https, dns

So I've moved a website to another server (from wordpress) and have transferred the domain. Previously, it had a ssl certificate in wordpress, but not now (not needed). So now, when I try to access it in a browser, it automatically redirects to https. I know how to remove it from the browser cache, but the problem is, all the users that had accessed the website before will have the same problem and they won't know how to solve it or won't be even interested in doing so. My client could be losing a lot of visitors because of that.

Is there any way to solve that without buying a ssl certificate? I only need to solve the browser cache problem, the website is all new and everything else works fine.

Thanks

Comment: Does this redirection (http to https) managed with htaccess file?

Comment: Run your site DNS through CloudFlare. They have a half-way HTTPS option. Your visitors can connect through either HTTPS or HTTP and the CF servers can connect to your HTTP-version site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot.

The mechanism you refer to is known as [Strict Transport Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security), and is specifically designed to prevent what you are trying to do.

However, you do not have to **buy** a certificate, you can get them for free using [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).

Comment: Thank you! at first I didn't succed, because I was using Vesta, then I found some script in github that filled the gap between let's encrypt and vesta.